# Unable to connect to Peer Js Server on deployed Website

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc, ejs, peerjs

So I recently made a Video Conferencing website using peerjs, socket.io and ejs.
Worked fine on my machine but when i wanted to deploy it on render I came across a issue.
In the dev environment I used 2 commands in the terminal 'nodemon script.js' to start the server and 'peerjs --port PORT_NO' to start the peerjs server in order to enable users to connect...
but when I deployed the site I am able to use the full functionality of the app just when 2 users join the same room they are not able to connect to one another.
I think it may be an issue with the peerjs server...
while building the website I put build function as 'nodemon script.js & peerjs --port 3001' which seems to be working...
I am all out of ideas and any feedback will be appreciated.

Here is the GitHub repo: [Repo](https://github.com/Paarth5/Video-Conferencing-Website)

And the deployed site: [Site](https://chat-fusion.onrender.com)

Server Side code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const PORT = process.env.PROD_PORT || 3000;
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const cors = require("cors");
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});
const path = require("path");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const localPassport = require("passport-local");
const User = require("./models/users");
const session = require("express-session");
const MemoryStore = require("memorystore")(session);
const { v4 } = require("uuid");
const { isLoggedIn, storeReturnTo } = require("./middleware");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

const sessionConfig = {
  secret: process.env.SECRET || "idkthesecret",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
  },
  store: new MemoryStore({
    checkPeriod: 86400000, // prune expired entries every 24h
  }),
};

app.use(session(sessionConfig));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cors());

passport.use(new localPassport(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@chatfusion.mfpslnx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=AtlasApp`;
mongoose
  .connect(uri)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB!!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error in connecting to Mongo", err);
  });
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/home");
});
app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", { user: req.user });
});
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login");
});
app.post(
  "/login",
  storeReturnTo,
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureFlash: false,
    failureRedirect: "/login",
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    redirectUrl = res.locals.returnTo || "/home";
    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
  }
);

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.render("register");
});
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { user } = req.body;
  const newUser = new User({ ...user, username: user.username });
  const regUser = await User.register(newUser, user.password);
  req.logIn(regUser, (err) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.redirect("/home");
  });
});
app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logOut((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.redirect("/home");
  });
});
app.get("/new", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/room/${v4()}`);
});
app.get("/join", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  res.render("join");
});
app.post("/join", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  res.redirect(`/room/${id}`);
});
app.get("/room/:id", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const user = req.user;
  res.render("room", { id, user });
});

// Socket.io wala part
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("join-room", (roomId, userId, userName) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit("user-connected", userId, userName);

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit("user-disconnected", userId);
    });
  });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Connected to server Port ${PORT} !!!`);
});
```

Client Side:

```
const socket = io("/");
const videoGrid = document.querySelector(".videoGrid");
const myPeer = new Peer(userId, {
  host: "/",
  port: "3001",
});
const container = document.createElement("div");
const dispName = document.createElement("span");
dispName.innerText = "You";
container.append(dispName);
const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
container.classList.add("videoContainer");
dispName.classList.add("dispName");
myVideo.classList.add("videoStream");
myVideo.muted = true;
myVideo.classList.add("me");
const peers = {};
const containers = {};

navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream, container);
    socket.on("user-connected", (userId, userName) => {
      console.log("user Connected", userName);
      connectToNewUser(userId, stream, userName);
    });
  });

myPeer.on("call", (call) => {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: true,
    })
    .then((stream) => {
      call.answer(stream);
    });
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  const dispName = document.createElement("span");
  dispName.innerText = `${call.metadata.userName}`;
  container.append(dispName);
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  container.classList.add("videoContainer");
  dispName.classList.add("dispName");
  video.classList.add("videoStream");
  call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream, container);
  });
  call.on("close", () => {
    video.remove();
    dispName.remove();
    container.remove();
  });
});

myPeer.on("open", () => {
  socket.emit("join-room", roomId, userId, userName);
});
socket.on("user-disconnected", (userId) => {
  if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close();
  if (containers[userId]) containers[userId].remove();
});

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream, newUserName) {
  const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream, { metadata: { userName } });
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  const dispName = document.createElement("span");
  container.classList.add("videoContainer");
  dispName.classList.add("dispName");
  video.classList.add("videoStream");
  dispName.innerText = `${newUserName}`;
  container.append(dispName);

  call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream, container);
  });
  call.on("close", () => {
    video.remove();
    dispName.remove();
    container.remove();
  });

  peers[userId] = call;
  containers[userId] = container;
}

function addVideoStream(video, stream, container) {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    video.play();
  });
  container.append(video);
  videoGrid.append(container);
}
```

IDK what else to say if you need any more information please leave a comment.